# aws xray and golang http call

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-xray

I'm trying to use awx xray on my go app that makes an http call to service. I simply followed this and am not sure if I missed something, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-go-httpclients.html

I make the http call like this:

```
payloadStr, _ := json.Marshal(dxPayload)

fmt.Println("size: ", int(unsafe.Sizeof(bytes.NewBuffer(payloadStr))))

clambda = &http.Client{}

//-------ADDED XRAY HERE-------//
xray.Client(clambda)

reqLambda, errReq := http.NewRequest("POST", lambdaurl, bytes.NewBuffer(payloadStr))
if errReq != nil {
    log.Fatal("Request Error: ", errReq)
    return
}

reqLambda.Header.Add("accept", "application/json;v=1")
reqLambda.Header.Add("cach-control", "no-cache")
reqLambda.Header.Add("content-type", "application/json")
reqLambda.Header.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + devexToken.AccessToken)

respLambda, errResp := clambda.Do(reqLambda)
if errResp != nil {
    log.Fatal("Status Response Error ", errResp)
    return
} else {

}
```

and in my `main.go` file, I have this in `func init()`

```
func init() {

    pConfig = createpConfig()

    //aws xray config
    ss, err := sampling.NewLocalizedStrategyFromFilePath("xray.json")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    xray.Configure(xray.Config{
        SamplingStrategy: ss,
    })
}
```

and my `xray.json` config looks like this:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "ehb",
      "service_name": "ehb-kafka-push",
      "http_method": "*",
      "url_path": "/private/api/calllambda/*",
      "fixed_target": 0,
      "rate": 0.85
    }
  ],
  "default": {
    "fixed_target": 1,
    "rate": 0.1
  }
}
```

now when I start my app...my api calls are making it through but I don't see anything in AWS xray and on my xray daemon locally, I only see this in the logs:

```
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 2.1.3
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Listening on UDP 127.0.0.1:2000
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 163 MB
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Info] 2608 segment buffers allocated
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Fetch region us-east-1 from commandline argument
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Info] Using region: us-east-1
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] ARN of the AWS resource running the daemon: 
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] No Metadata set for telemetry records
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Telemetry initiated
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2018-08-26T18:45:04-07:00 [Debug] Batch size: 50
2018-08-26T18:46:04-07:00 [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2018-08-26T18:47:04-07:00 [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2018-08-26T18:48:04-07:00 [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
```

what am I missing here? everything seems to be working except the Xray part, why am I not getting any data or errors?

Comment: You probably need to manually begin an X-Ray segment to kick of collection. I can only speak of Pyhton, but there that's something AWS Lambda does for you and you have to do it yourself everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In Lambda scenario, Lambda is responsible for creating Segments and AWS X-Ray Golang SDK only creates Subsegments and then emits them. Based on your code snippet, you didn't find the code that you instrument your application with X-Ray Go SDK APIs to generate subsegments inside Lambda functions. Here I attached a link where you can find how to instrument your application: [lambdadocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-tracing.html)